# How to build a dynamic table from python selenium data?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to generate a dynamic table and email that table with the help of python selenium.

With WebDriver, we were able to get the dynamic data of required fields. But I couldn't able to tabulate those data in a single table. I tried with email function in a loop.

```
TotalBugs = int(TotalBugs) + 1 
# BugList = [] 
for ID in range(1, TotalBugs): 
BugID = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+ str(ID) +']/td[2]/a[1]').get_attribute('href') 
Summary = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+ str(ID)+']/td[3]/p[1]').text 
Reporter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+str(ID)+']/td[5]/span[1]/a[1]').text 
Resolution = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+str(ID)+']/td[8]').text 
UpdatedDate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+str(ID)+']/td[10]/span[1]/time[1]').text 
print(BugID, Summary, Reporter, Resolution, UpdatedDate) 
tabular = [(BugID, Summary, Reporter, Resolution, UpdatedDate)] 
  for BugID, Summary, Reporter, Resolution, UpdatedDate in tabular: 
   tabular = [(BugID, Summary, Reporter, Resolution, UpdatedDate)] 
   message = "<thead><tr><th>Bug ID</th><th>Summary</th><th>Reporter</th><th>Resolution</th><th>Updated Date</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>"+BugID+"</td><td>"+Summary+"</td><td>"+Reporter+"</td><td>"+Resolution+"</td><td>"+UpdatedDate+"</td></tr></tbody>" 
   SERVER = "xyz.smtp.com" 
   me = "xyz@xyz.com" 
   you = "xyz@xyz.com" # must be a list 
   msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative') 
   msg['Subject'] = "Daily report" + " - " + str(currentdate()) 
   msg['From'] = me 
   msg['To'] = you 
   html = "<html> <body><p> Hi team</p><p>Please find the below mentioned tasks for today:</p><table class='table table-bordered ' border='1'>"+ message +"</table></body></html>" 
   # part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain') 
   part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html') 
   # msg.attach(part1) 
   msg.attach(part2) 
   print(msg) 
   server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER) 
   server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string()) 
   server.quit()
```

With the above code I received the email as per how many rows in the table. But I need all those data in a single table like below in single email

**Expected output :**

```
| BugID | Summary | Reporter | Resolution | Updated Date |
|-------|---------|----------|------------|--------------|
| Bug1  | title1  | rep1     | res1       | 07/07/2019   |
| Bug2  | tit2    | rep2     | res2       | 08/08/2019   |
| Bug3  | tit3    | rep3     | res3       | 09/09/2019   |
```

Comment: untested, you could use pandas df to store the data and use the to_html method on the data frame https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?#pandas-dataframe-to-html. Eg, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564407/pandas-send-email-containing-dataframe-as-a-visual-table

Comment: No @Satish, It won't help me in getting all those data in a single email

Comment: my bad then, I am sure some expert will crack it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below logic.

```
message = "<thead><tr><th>Bug ID</th><th>Summary</th><th>Reporter</th><th>Resolution</th><th>Updated Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
TotalBugs = int(TotalBugs) + 1
# BugList = []
for ID in range(1, TotalBugs):
    BugID = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+ str(ID) +']/td[2]/a[1]').get_attribute('href')
    Summary = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+ str(ID)+']/td[3]/p[1]').text
    Reporter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+str(ID)+']/td[5]/span[1]/a[1]').text
    Resolution = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+str(ID)+']/td[8]').text
    UpdatedDate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//issuetable-web-component[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr['+str(ID)+']/td[10]/span[1]/time[1]').text
    print(BugID, Summary, Reporter, Resolution, UpdatedDate)
    newRow = "< tr > < td > " + BugID + " < / td > < td > " + Summary + " < / td > < td > " + Reporter + " < / td > < td > " + Resolution+" < / td > < td > "+UpdatedDate+" < / td > < / tr >"
    message = message+newRow
message = message + "</tbody>"
SERVER = "xyz.smtp.com"
me = "xyz@xyz.com"
you = "xyz@xyz.com" # must be a list
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Daily report" + " - " + str(currentdate())
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
html = "<html> <body><p> Hi team</p><p>Please find the below mentioned tasks for today:</p><table class='table table-bordered ' border='1'>"+ message +"</table></body></html>"
# part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
# msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
print(msg)
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```