# Sending a dataframe via email

Tags: python, html, pandas, smtp, mime

I'm trying to send a dataframe through email but the end result is quite ugly. See my code below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

data =pd.read_excel('/Users/juliobermudez/desktop/ASN/asn.xlsx', usecols =[14,7,21,22])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_html = df.to_html()
neat = MIMEText(df_html, 'html')

#groups = df.groupby('Cust.Name')


#w = groups.get_group('ALPS ELECTRIC(NORTH AMERICA), INC')
#print(w)

#for key, value in df.groupby('Cust.Name'):
#    print(value)

msg = 'Subject:15' + '\n\n Hello,\n\n The following email contains tracking information and Packing slips for todays shipments. \n ' + str(neat)

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.login('x', 'x')
smtpObj.sendmail('x', 'x', msg)
smtpObj.quit()
```

My email looks like when you utilize the developer tools to inspect a website. I simply want to paste the dataframe in the email in a neat manner, nothing out of the ordinary. A simple table would suffice.

Any ideas ? You can see by my subject line that I'm on my 15th attempt lol

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564407/pandas-send-email-containing-dataframe-as-a-visual-table

Comment: @matthewborish what you said before and the attached link do the same thing, they turn it into a string. When I turn it into a string the formatting of the columns is not correct