# encoding without a string argument for sending email attachment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, email, aws-lambda

I am trying to get my dataframe into my email attachment. The below code fails with the error:

"errorMessage": "encoding without a string argument",

```
 s_buf = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(s_buf)
byte_buf = bytes(s_buf, 'utf-8')
att= MIMEApplication(byte_buf)
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='+ 'dataframe.csv')
msg.attach(att)
```

Comment: ``s_buf`` is empty, possibly you need to ``io.StringIO(text)``

Comment: Is this from a python traceback? If so, post it.

Comment: It would be easy to make a running example for us to test. And you really do need to post the traceback message so we can see where the error is. Trying to convert a StringIO object to bytes isn't going to work. But you could seek(0) and just read and encode it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert a Dataframe to a table and attach it in email or etc, please look at this answer:
[Pandas send email containing dataframe as a visual table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50566309/14108630)