# Sending a pandas Dataframe using smtplib

Tags: python, pandas, smtplib

I've seen a lot of threads here about this topic, however, none regarding this specific question.

I am sending a email with a pandas dataframe (df) as an html using pandas built in df.to_html() method. The email sends successfully. However, the df is displayed in the email as html, not in the desired table format. Can anyone offer assistance on how to ensure the df is displayed as a table, not in html in the email?  The code is below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

MY_LAT = 
MY_LNG = 
API_KEY = ""

parameters = {
    "lat": MY_LAT,
    'lon': MY_LNG,
    'exclude': "",
    "appid": API_KEY
}

df = pd.read_csv("OWM.csv")

response = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall", params=parameters)
response.raise_for_status()

data = response.json()
consolidated_weather_12hour = []
for i in range(0, 12):
    consolidated_weather_12hour.append((data['hourly'][i]['weather'][0]['id']))

hour7_forecast = []
for hours in consolidated_weather_12hour:
    weather_id = df[df.weather_id == hours]
    weather_description = weather_id['description']
    for desc in weather_description.iteritems():
        hour7_forecast.append(desc[1])

times = ['7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM']
col_header = ["Description of Expected Weather"]
weather_df = pd.DataFrame(data=hour7_forecast, index=times, columns=col_header)

my_email = ""
password = ""
html_df = weather_df.to_html()

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as connection:
    connection.starttls()  # Makes connection secure
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="",
                        msg=f"Subject: 12 Hour Forecast Sterp"
                            """\
                            <html>
                                <head></head>"
                                <body>
                                    {0}
                                <body>
                            </html>
                            """.format(html_df))
```

Comment: Does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564407/pandas-send-email-containing-dataframe-as-a-visual-table/50566309

Comment: I've read that post, and tried to wrangle around my code to get it in table format in the email but to no avail.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the piece you are missing

Answer (score 0):

just use `df.to_html()` to convert it into an html table that you can include in your html email

then when you send the mail you **must** set the mimetype to html

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP("...")
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = subject_line
msg['From'] = from_addr
msg['To'] = ','.join(to_addrs)

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
part1 = MIMEText(plaintext, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg.as_string())
```

you can use the library `html2text` to convert your html to markdown for clients that do not support html content (not many these days) if you do not feel like writing the plaintext on your own

as an aside... using jinja when you are working with html tends to simplify things...

Comment: that's what I am doing, am I not? However, it isn't appearing in the email as a table, but in html. I'm not sure how to ensure it appears as a table in the email.

Comment: edited ... you just need  to send it as the html  mime type

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am getting the following error when executing the code with this, if you can offer any insight, it would be great. Understandable if not: 
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:line 16, in <module>
    smtp.sendmail(msg["From"], msg["To"], msg.as_string())
  File "C:\Users\shann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 882, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i18sm4899200qkk.115 - gsmtp', 'gmail account')```

Comment: you still need to do the starttls and login stuff ... you just have to send the right mimetype