# How to send tabular list content in an email body python

Tags: python, email, tabulate

I have a list which is a combination of splitted dataframe as below and I am trying to send teh content of it in an email body using email.message package. The string variable in the picture is what is passed to msg.set_content(text) function.

[image]

Unfortunately the result of this is not in the format as what I was expecting :

[image]

Any suggestion or quick fix  ?

Answer (score 0):

The Jupyter Notebook output can show the table nicely due to the use of a monospaced font. However, showing that string in a font that is not monospaced likely can't replicate the structure table as a   is not the same width as a `-` character. I'd suggest looking at getting the output as a `html` table instead. A suggestion can be found here: [Pandas send email containing dataframe as a visual table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564407/pandas-send-email-containing-dataframe-as-a-visual-table/50566309). In particular, as you are using `pandas`, you can export the table as HTML using `df.to_html()`, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: So I tried to convert the dataframe into html format and send it to email using MIME pkg. What I am strill struggling is to get the html table as an inline email body. With my code as below I am getting as an attachment . Part 1 is a general text with some details and Part 2 is an html table.                                                                  msg = MIMEMultipart("mixed")
msg['Subject']= 'Please ignore these emails - testing'
msg['From']= emailofsender
msg['To']=receiptaddress
part1 = MIMEText(string, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(t4, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)